# What's the proper way to use gzerr?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to use gzerr to output error messages to the console in which gazebo is running from.  If I put the following code in my model plugin's load method, the gzerr text never shows in the console.

```
gzerr << "this message never gets displayed\n";
std::cout << "this message gets displayed just fine" << std::endl;
```

I'm starting gazebo using the "gazebo" command, and I have verified with an std::cout that the plugin's load method is getting called.  I've also made sure that gazebo/common/Console.h is included.  I've also tried using sdferr the same way as gzerr, and sdferr works exactly as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13099/what%27s-the-proper-way-to-use-gzerr?/) by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 207 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Run Gazebo in verbose mode:

```
gazebo --verbose
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on 2016-04-14**:
Thanks!  Interesting that by default error messages won't show up.  What's the proper way then, to notify the user of an error if not running in verbose mode?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-04-14**:
It depends on the "user". If it's someone who will be using the command line, you'd use the verbose mode. If it's a graphical interface user, you could make a GUI plugin which prints messages to the screen.